# Как сделать размытую подложку под фото?

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите как сделать размытую подложку под фото как на авито?

[image: Пример подложки на Avito]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`filter()`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) и `blur()` для размытия заднего фона.

```css
#back {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2.5px);
  filter: blur(2.5px);
  width: 100%;
}

#front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="back" src="https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/images/lakeandballoon.jpg" alt="Pineapple" height="300">

<img id="front" src="https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/images/lakeandballoon.jpg" alt="Pineapple" height="300">
```